# Immutable-but-refreshable collections?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, guava

A common pattern I am encountering is a need to refresh a collection like a List or a HashMap from a database but don't want values added or removed from it in between refreshes.

I recently discovered the ImmutableList and ImmutableMap in Google's Guava library which I like a lot. But I cannot do a "clearAll()" on these types nor repopulate them. But I like that they are immutable beyond that.

So if I wanted to enforce this pattern of "only make mutable on a database refresh", I guess I would have to use a volatile variable each time? Or is there a better pattern? This can be in a multithreaded environment too, and I would ensure there's no race conditions on the refresh();

```
 public class MarketManager {

     private volatile ImmutableList<Market> markets = null;

     private MarketManager() { 
     }

     public void refresh() { 
         marketList = //build a new immutable market list
     }

     public static MarketManager getInstance() { 
         MarketManager marketManager = new MarketManager();
         marketManager.refresh();
         return marketManager;
     }
}
```

Comment: You can use `Collections.unmodifiableList()`; return this from a method within a class which has the ability to override that list.

Comment: But what if I wanted the performance improvement of the Guava implementations? The applications I write use a lot of collections and a lot of memory.

Comment: It should be noted that `Collections.unmodifiableFoos()` return an immutable view of the original `foo`, so they're very efficient.

Comment: So if I have a non-threadsafe ArrayList backing an unmodifiableList wrapper, that makes the UnmodifiableList wrapper threadsafe as long as the ArrayList is not accessed directly?

Comment: Don't clear and repopulate - on refresh, build a new one and swap it in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how you could code your class so that you use `Collections.unmodifiableList()`:

```
public class MarketManager {

     private volatile List<Market> markets = Collections.emptyList();

     private MarketManager() { 
     }

     public void refresh() { 
         marketList = //build a new market list
     }

     public List<Market> getMarkets() {
         return Collections.unmodifiableList(markets);
     }

     // ...
}
```

`Collections.unmodifiableList()` simply wraps any `List` implementation so that all mutation operations are "disabled" (that is, they throw an exception).

Answer (score 1):

I think you're trying to mix together two concepts: unmodifiable objects and immutable objects.

Unmodifiable objects are objects that YOU cannot modify. However, they can be changed "under you" by other actors. Such objects are useful when you need to control access to your object's internal state. However, they are not useful for thread safety or optimization.

Immutable objects are truly immutable. Once created, they cannot be changed. Not by you, not by anyone. They offer all the advantages of unmodifiable objects, plus they permit optimizations and guarantee thread safety.

What you're proposing will turn an immutable collection (created and frozen) into an unmodifiable one (I can't change it, but it can be refreshed from the DB). Just use unmodifiable collection framework from Java, no need to chang ethe Guava immutable collections.